# Is it true that (P∧Q≡P)⇔(Q≡⊤)?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

Consider the statement

> (P∧Q≡P)⇔(Q≡⊤)

Where `P` and `Q` are statements, and `⊤` denotes the tautology (true) statement. It seems intuitively true that the above biconditional statement is true. But I would like to prove it.

One direction is easy enough to prove: suppose `Q≡⊤`; then by substitution, we have

> P∧Q ≡ P∧⊤ ≡ P

by the [identity law for conjunction](http://cstaecker.fairfield.edu/~cstaecker/classwiki/index.php/Algebra_of_logic).

However, the converse seems trickier. By assuming `P∧Q≡P`, how would one know for certain that `Q≡⊤`?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

(P.S. Is it improper of me to use [two different symbols for equivalence](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/26719/is-there-a-content-based-equivalence-of-statements-separate-from-truth-tables) here?)

Comment: Those symbols look a bit strange, yes. I would use a double arrow. Concerning the proof, you could simply use a truth table. Otherwise, make case distinctions over both P and Q (which is the equivalent of a truth table in natural deduction).

Comment: Check with a truth-table : it seems not true ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is true that :

> **(Q≡⊤) ⊨ (P∧Q≡P)**

we can check it with a truth-table.

But the other "direction" does not hold : when **P** and **Q** are both **false**, we have that **(P∧Q≡P)** is **true** but **(Q≡⊤)** is not.

Answer (score 3):

As an example: P = "A person is more than 40 years old", Q = "A person is more than 30 years old". P ^ Q means "A person is both more than 40 years old and more than 30 years old", which is obviously equivalent to just P. But Q is not a tautology at all.

P∧Q≡P means that Q is true whenever P is true. Nothing more. You can't jump from this to the conclusion that Q is *always* true.

Comment: Very concrete and illustrative example - helped me think about and understand it. Thanks @Gnasher729!

Answer (score 0):

Is it true that (P∧Q≡P)⇔(Q≡⊤)?

No.

1. ((P&Q)<->P) <-> (P->Q).
2. (Q<->⊤) <-> Q.
3. [(P->Q) <-> Q] <-> (PVQ).

Therefore,

4. [(P∧Q≡P)⇔(Q≡⊤)] <-> (PvQ).